# What is an alternative to not using child theme to customize a WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, theme-options

I'm using a premium parent theme and I've been trying to create a child theme from it and found that some "templates" are not just as simple as overidding them. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495702/child-theme-doesnt-read-template-part-file)

So, that is the other best alternative technique of customizing an existing theme? Could I just use file comparing software like DiffMerge and find the changes each time there's an update for the theme?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Your question will likely be flagged and closed (see this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) but I will say there is really no reason to keep a theme updated with the latest version all of the time.  Vulnerabilities can be an issue but modifying the theme for your own purposes should not be a problem.  Use version control and as long as you are not working on your live/production site, this is a good path to advance your WP knowledge.  When you get stuck, come back and ask a very specific question for help.

Comment: You should contact the theme developers to see if they can push an update for this type of customization. Maybe this is a simple fix that can be pushed with an update.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee the developer actually made big changes to the latest version and I have trouble coping via child theme cos some changes are not plain-old templates. And not all classes are child-friendly such as with no "if class does not exist" syntax.